# readLines, parse XML stream message to read into data frame in R Studio

Tags: java, r, xml, readlines

I need some help with reading XML formatted messages into a data frame.

I have a java application that is connected via fifos and stream2()to R.From R I run my application, which looks like this:

```
runBroker <- function(input, output) {
  # wd is where the fifos and the pom.xml sit
  #setwd("..")
  library(XML)
  pr <- parallel:::mcfork()
  if (inherits(pr, "masterProcess")) {
    # this is the child process
    #print("child process")
    childOut <- fifo(input, open="w", blocking=TRUE)
    childIn <- fifo(output, open="r", blocking=TRUE)
    args <- c("exec:exec", " -Dexec.args='", "--prop     samplebroker.r.charStreamAdapter.inputFilename:", output,  " --prop     samplebroker.r.charStreamAdapter.outputFilename:", input, "'")
#print(paste(args))
#writeLines(args, childOut)
writeLines(paste(args, collapse=""), childOut)
#writeLines(c("<tsx/>", "<ts-done ts=32/>"), childOut)
system2("mvn", args=paste(args, collapse=""))
close(childOut)
parallel:::mcexit("child exit")
  }
      # parent process
  print("start parent")
  infile <- fifo(input, open="r", blocking=TRUE)
  outfile <- fifo(output, open="w", blocking=TRUE)

  done <- FALSE
  while (!done) {
line <- readLines(infile, n=1)
xline <- xmlParse(readLines(infile, n=1))
if (length(line) == 0) {
  print("parent done")
  done <- TRUE
}
# process lines, send messages
   print(line)


if (!is.na(charmatch("<ts-done", c(line))))
{
  # process input here
  writeLines(c("continue"), outfile)
}
  }

  close(infile)
  close(outfile)
}
```

When I run this file, it throws the messages into the R console, which works fine. However, in my environment I can not see "line", the only object created is the runBroker function. 
Following code is a sample of what I receive in the R console. I want to write them into several data frames.

```
   <competition id="0" name="t2b" pomId="1.3.1-SNAPSHOT" timeslotLength="60" bootstrapTimeslotCount="336" bootstrapDiscardedTimeslots="24" timeslotsOpen="24" deactivateTimeslotsAhead="1" minimumOrderQuantity="0.01" timezoneOffset="-6" latitude="45" simulationRate="720" simulationModulo="3600000">
  <description></description>
  <simulationBaseTime>
    <iMillis>1255132800000</iMillis>
  </simulationBaseTime>
  <broker>default broker</broker>
  <broker>Sample</broker>
  <customer id="3840" name="b12" population="1" powerType="BATTERY_STORAGE" customerClass="SMALL" controllableKW="-40.0
" upRegulationKW="-40.0" downRegulationKW="40.0" storageCapacity="90.0" multiContracting="false" canNegotiate="false"/>
  <customer id="4096" name="HighIncome-2_10" population="1" powerType="ELECTRIC_VEHICLE" customerClass="SMALL" controllableKW="-6.6" upRegulationKW="-6.6" downRegulationKW="6.6" storageCapacity="24.0" multiContracting="false" canNegotiate="false"/>
  <customer id="4099" name="HighIncome-2_11" population="1" powerType="ELECTRIC_VEHICLE" customerClass="SMALL" controllableKW="-6.6" upRegulationKW="-6.6" downRegulationKW="6.6" storageCapacity="24.0" multiContracting="false" canNegotiate="false"/>
  <customer id="3332" name="DowntownOffices" population="30" powerType="CONSUMPTION" customerClass="SMALL" controllableKW="0.0" upRegulationKW="0.0" downRegulationKW="0.0" storageCapacity="0.0" multiContracting="true" canNegotiate="false"/>
</competition>

<customer-bootstrap-data id="938315" customerName="CentervilleHomes" powerType="CONSUMPTION">
<netUsage>-12391.35,-10114.47,-10140.86,-11078.46,-11878.63,-14476.89,-13162.94,-14258.63,-14123.5,-14169.36,-13705.84,-14090.340000000002,...    </netUsage>
</customer-bootstrap-data>

<market-bootstrap-data id="938607">
  <mwh>40.95884800000005,40.328089861100096,43.10454465350664,51.85378530783136,54.49313841123366,60.92061090600654,44.605544455502276,59.36643951972485,...</mwh>
  <marketPrice>-124.12755392710862,-17.709759037038168,-34.78745750315098,-21    8.34365565481434,-81.44333206309733,-205.4500215178752,-20.06859471666362,-33.03741812546915</marketPrice>
</market-bootstrap-data>

<weather-report id="626" currentTimeslot="24" temperature="11.3"     windSpeed="3.0" windDirection="250.0" cloudCover="0.5"/>
2127 INFO  core.BrokerMessageReceiver: onMessage(String) - received message:
<weather-report id="627" currentTimeslot="25" temperature="11.7" windSpeed="3.0" windDirection="250.0" cloudCover="0.125"/>
2127 INFO  core.BrokerMessageReceiver: onMessage(String) - received message:
<weather-report id="628" currentTimeslot="26" temperature="10.8" windSpeed="2.0" windDirection="240.0" cloudCover="1.0"/>
2128 INFO  core.BrokerMessageReceiver: onMessage(String) - received message:
<weather-report id="629" currentTimeslot="27" temperature="11.5" windSpeed="2.0" windDirection="230.0" cloudCover="1.0"/>
```

I have code that successfully reads the data from an xml file, however I use the xpathSapply function which did not want to work when I implemented it in the code:

```
##------------Customers------------##
# MATRIX OF CUSTOMER ATTRIBS
customer <- xpathSApply(doc=xml, path="//customer",  xmlAttrs)

# TRANSPOSE TO DATA FRAME
customer <- data.frame(t(customer))

##------------net usage per cusotmer------------##------#source:         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565910/xpath-select-two-consecutive-    elements-and-transform-them-into-one-data-frame/37566740#37566740


customerBoot <- xpathSApply(doc=xml, path="//customer-bootstrap-data", xmlAttrs)
customerBoot <- data.frame(t(customerBoot), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

customerBoot <- data.table::rbindlist(apply(customerBoot, 1, function(x) {

  path <- sprintf("//customer-bootstrap-data[@id='%s']/netUsage", x["id"])
  vals <- strsplit(xpathSApply(doc=xml, path=path, xmlValue), ",")[[1]]
  c(as.list(x), as.list(setNames(as.numeric(vals), sprintf("X%d", 1:length(vals)))))

}), fill=TRUE)

colnames(customerBoot)[2] <- "customer"


##------------market bootstrap data------------##------#-------

marketBootmwh <- strsplit(xpathSApply(doc=xml, path="//market-bootstrap-data/mwh", xmlValue), ",")[[1]]
marketBootmarketPrice <- strsplit(xpathSApply(doc=xml, path="//market-bootstrap-data/marketPrice", xmlValue), ",")[[1]]
marketBootmwh <- as.data.frame(marketBootmwh)
marketBootmarketPrice <- as.data.frame(marketBootmarketPrice)
marketBoot <- cbind(marketBootmwh, marketBootmarketPrice)

##------------weather-report------------##
# MATRIX OF weather 
weather <- xpathSApply(doc=xml, path="//weather-report",  xmlAttrs)

# TRANSPOSE TO DATA FRAME
weather <- data.frame(t(weather))
```

I am just not sure how to read it via the readLines function. I read that I have to parse the readLine function to make it a DOM, which I can then transform into a data frame is that correct? Which xml function would work with that? The xmlparse and parse didn't seem to work, but it might also be me implementing it incorrectly.

Comment: Regarding your point: "However, in my environment I can not see "line", the only object created is the runBroker function."  Objects created inside functions don't appear in the global environment. If you want to use them later you need the function to return them. However I'm not sure how that relates to your broader question.

Comment: @PhilippeMarchand that solves one of my questions at least! Thanks!